# Research topics in combinatorics for high school students.

Tags: combinatorics, research

I'm a 12th grade high school students. I was looking for some research stuff from combinatorics within my capabilities.

My background: I am introduced to olympiad mathematics. So I am introduced to the basic olympiad combinatorics stuff. Considering these, can anyone please suggest some research topic in combinatorics within my abilities?

Thank you.

Comment: The International Mathematics Olympiad?

Comment: Try a computation of a concrete problem; not a conjecture or something.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy, I didn't understand your question.

Comment: @E2R0NS, could you please give me an example? Or maybe even show me such type of a problem , please?